# AWS Statemachine not able to pass input json data to the first Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, state-machine

I have a AWS Step Function, that is trigger by a proxy lambda, which passes the below input data.

This data is available in the step function execution Input.
But in the state definition, as a first step there is one Lambda,
This Lambda is not receiving this input json.

What I am missing, please?

**Step Function Input Data:-**

```
{
  "bucketName": "mybucket",
  "key": "12321321.zip",
  "id": "20210923144805753"
}
```

**Step Function:-**

```
StartAt: UnPackContents
States:
  UnPackContents:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke
    Parameters:
      FunctionName: ${UnPackFunctionArn}
    Next: InvokeFCS
  InvokeFCS:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

InputPath selects which parts of the JSON input to pass to the task of the Task state (for example, an AWS Lambda function). ResultPath then selects what combination of the state input and the task result to pass to the output. OutputPath can filter the JSON output to further limit the information that's passed to the output.

Comment: Thanks, I want to pass all the full input data from the state machine to the UnpackContents lambda.

Comment: Its my pleasure.

Comment: it's my pleasure too